how to compose typescript interface key conditional type
interface A{
 multiple : boolean;
 something : any
}

const someThingFunction = (props:A)=>{
}

A something depending on the status of multiple
If multiple is true, I want you to return something : string[] and if false, I want you to return something: string.
How can I do what I want
What I've tried is
interface A{
 multiple : boolean;
 something : A['multiple'] extends true ? string[] : string
 something : CCC['multiple'] extends true ? string[] : string
}

type CCC = {
  multiple?:boolean
}




but always return string

You probably want a union, type A = {multiple: true, something: string[]} | {multiple: false, something: string} But without a [mre] of how you're using it I'm not sure. Does that meet your needs? If not, please [edit] to show how your use case needs something else.
